# Clarification on maintaining 401 K Account with Ex-Employer?

Tags: 401k

A year ago, I changed my job and holding new 401K with my current Employer. I have not transferred my previous 401 K account to my new Employer.

I still maintain my existing 401 K account with my previous Employer. I haven't seen any Interest Rate growth in my previous 401K Account.

In this case, can i transfer my previous 401K account to my new 401 K Account and get some financial advise to diversify my portfolio ?

Comment: First, _read [this question](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/22829/5760) and its answers,_ and decide whether you really want to roll over 401k assets into the new plan, If the answer is Yes, _then_ ask your _new_ employer's HR department if the new 401k plan _accepts_ rollovers from other 401k plans: not all 401k plans allow this.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly roll over your old 401(k).  I would, however, strongly advise against rolling it over to your new 401(k) plan.  Once you do that you can only invest in the plans in the current employer's 401(k).  Typically (almost always) these have high fees and limited choices.

I would recommend that you roll over your old 401(k) to a Traditional IRA.  You will have access to many, many more funds and be able to find funds with low expenses.  If you get a Traditional IRA at a company like Vanguard or Fidelity don't have to worry about selecting specific funds for diversification.  You can use their Target Date funds or contact them for suggestions on a target Asset Allocation.